# How would I implement a get Max element function in F#?

Tags: f#

I am pretty new to F# and having trouble with some basic functions.
I am given a list:

```
let list1 = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7]
```

**How would I create a `getMax` function that recursively iterates through `list1` and finds the largest element?**

What I am most confused about is what I would be returning and how I would iterate through the list.

Comment: I disagree with the closing of this question, based on the reason given. I can't see how it is not focused, since it's a very simple question that requires a very simple solution, and asks for very specific details regarding the solution. How can it be more focused than this? Also, OP is a new contributor.

Comment: I agree @BentTranberg. I tweaked the wording a little, hopefully it gets re-opened.

Comment: @jake-diaz, I'm sorry on behalf of StackOverflow.

Here is one [solution](https://try.fsharp.org/#?code=DYUwLgBMCWDOYEYIF4IG0EG4BMmDMmALJgKyYBsmA7ALoBQdokATiAMYQDm4AsgIYAPKPBR0IEALZ8wbABbDIAd2hhZYiAB90NCAFoAfBABmfaMGWqIAIm5h+Qtn2CgAJhAD2AOwh9vICQAOYACeUHBgVupaaBBCOgaxUbEQAFwpsbB6hlJCQgAUtvYZAJQMAczQnmBG3lYApC5WEAW8gmHwCMVAA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAsAKAAQqaApgQwCb2ag4CdMTJcMABwFp0BHAVwEsA3AXgCIBhAewDsw6AdQAqAT0roOSAMb9BAzoIAeYAPThoAbhkhMAJwDOJNgzAAzagA4OeQhqy5EhAEY9sYu6mBq3HvD6asEA&css=Q). It throws an exception if you call it on an empty list.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Closing this was a mistake.

Comment: Why recursion? [List.max](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html) is already available and throws if the list is empty. [It loops over the list](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L572) and uses a mutable variable to keep the max value found up to that point

Answer (score 3):

Analogous to how, in an imperative language, you would loop through each item and store the maximum value in a variable, we write a tail-recursive function which will be translated by the compiler into a loop.

```
let getMax list =
    let rec loop current list = 
        match list with
        | [] -> current
        | head::tail -> loop (if head > current then head else current) tail

    loop (List.head list) list
```

This is verbose, but it's a good starting point.
Of course there's always `List.max` and `List.maxBy`, but understanding the analogue of a loop is an essential part of it.

Comment: List itself uses looping and a volatile `acc` variable, as functions like `max` and `min` are performance-critical for all applications

Comment: Most core operations in F# internally use mutable state, and some use inline IL. And this is most important when your compiler is self-hosted. But the code above is translated by the compiler into a while loop with a mutable variable. https://sharplab.io#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfYBTALgAgE4oMYeAHtCAHDXAVyxwDtNgBLCTAXgwFgAoDHjAWwCGaXAAsCTTAHcGaEV14ZEGANoBdDAFoAfOSq0083kpEoBcEGgENgmnUVIYAFAzAYTZjDsrUUdDLN83UxgMFGAIFF0fOgBKfytgLi5UTABzdABZAQAPcWYMFkMeezJHABkJADp3EMZmOLq0IA===

Comment: F# is a multi-paradigm language that doesn't force you into writing immutable code, but you get much safer code by having immutable semantics, and let the compiler do its job. Hotspots can always be profiled later.